# How to test all possible iterations in a multiple linear regresion and return the best R-Squared and P values combination

Tags: python, linear-regression, correlation, statsmodels

I am trying to get the best combination to reach the best R Squared and P value. In this case, I have 6 columns to run the code, but I have the R-Squared and P values just for this combo ([col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5] vs [col6]). I want to test all the possible combinations, something like:

[col0] vs [col6]

[col0 + col1] vs [col6]

[col0 + col1 + col2] vs [col6]...

Is there any way to automatize this? So I dont have to run all possible combinations on hand.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn import linear_model

X = df_norm[["col0", 
"col1", 
"col2", 
"col3", 
"col4", 
"col5"]]

y = df_norm["col6"]

import statsmodels.api as sm
# with statsmodels
X = sm.add_constant(X)
 
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

print_model = model.summary()
```

Comment: I think you can pull out the value of R-squared and P-value from sklearn. when you pull out the value, run a number of iteration of 50 or 100 depending on your choice. then, compare the previous value of r-squared and value if they are greater than the current value. lastly, save it on pickle and just load the pickle that has the highest value based on your simulation.

Comment: On my real database I have 230 columns. Can you give me an example of a code to make the iteration?

Comment: You don't want to iterate over all possible combinations if you have 230 columns. That's a total of 2**230 combinations. You should figure out a better filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking to implement is the `powerset` function shown in the `iterools` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    #"powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Then you could iterate over each subset of your columns and process the results as needed. Your loop would be something like:

```
for subset in powerset(X.columns):
    if len(subset) > 0:
        model = sm.OLS(y, X[list(subset)]).fit()
```

Comment: Do I have to change this numbers to my columns names?

"powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"

 With my code, its returning me:

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

Comment: No that's just a comment.

Comment: import pandas

from sklearn import linear_model

X = df_norm[["col0", 
"col1", 
"col2", 
"col3", 
"col4", 
"col5",]]

y = df_norm["col6"]

from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

import statsmodels.api as sm
# with statsmodels
X = sm.add_constant(X) # adding a constant
 
for subset in powerset(X.columns):
    model = sm.OLS(y, X[list(subset)]).fit()
print(print_model)

Comment: I ran that code /\ and Its returning me:  ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

Comment: Edited - but please try to do the basic debugging yourself. The error is self explanatory.

Comment: ok, I will try. Sorry. Im learning this kkk. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @tpt369 - do NOT run this code for a dataframe with 230 columns. That is a ridiculously high number of combinations.

Comment: okay, I will try to get the simple pearson from each column and select the 15 best columns to use.

Comment: it worked, thank you. I will try to evolve this code. I want to store all rsquared results in a list of variables, and bring me the model with the best result.